# Why my serial message won't show on another when I try use 2 Arduino communication

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, softwareserial

I am trying to make a simple chatting program with my 2 arduino uno and 2 PC. But when I tried write a message using PC1 serial monitor the message won't show up on PC2 serial monitor. I can't see the problem or maybe I miss something on the program.

Here is my code:
PC1:

```c
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial Serial1(10,11);

void setup() 
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
    Serial1.begin(9600);
}

void loop() 
{
    if ( Serial.available()) // Check to see if at least one character is available
    {
        char ch1 = Serial.read();
        Serial1.print(ch1);
    }

    delay(200);
}
```

PC2:

```c
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial Serial1(10,11);

void setup() 
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
    Serial1.begin(9600);
}

void loop() 
{
    if (Serial1.available()) 
    {
        char ch = Serial1.read();
        Serial.print(ch); 
    }
}
```

Comment: did you cross the wires RX to TX? use `write` not `print`

Comment: Yeah I wires RX to TX. So I should use write instead print?

Comment: The `delay(200)` is not necessary -- why is it there? It just creates annoying delays in the output

Comment: Did you tie the grounds together?

Comment: I see maybe I can just remove the code then

Comment: Try out this thing. It may be helpful for concept purpose. [link](https://www.instructables.com/id/Communication-Between-Two-Arduinos-I2C/)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this in a while but it has been my experience that even though you can have multiple IDE windows open, you can only have one Serial Monitor at a time. The way I got around this is to use a Terminal Emulator program for the second Arduino.